# Get attribute value from bad xsl formatted document

Tags: java, xml

I have a bad formatted xsl documented as an input, from where I should extract some cell values based on row and column.
I say bad formatted because when I open it with Excel I get a warning: `The file format and extension of ... don't match.`.

The xml behind the xsl file looks like this:

```
<Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
       <Data ss:Type="String">Cell1</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">n/a</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
```

I managed to get the full node with the following code:

```
File fXmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Worksheet"); // getting the tags "Worksheet"
Node nNode = nList.item(0); // getting the first "worksheet" tag
Element eElement = (Element) nNode; //getting the content of the worksheet tag
String td = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Row").item(1).getTextContent(); // item(1) gets the second "Row" tag
```

Which if I print it looks something like this:

```
      Cell1


      n/a
```

How can I acces only the second  element?

Comment: can you post a larger part of the code, how are you printing the element? Using a loop?

Comment: @KAD updated, is it clearer now?

Comment: You are getting all the text nodes within the second row when you print the string of `getTextContext()`, isn't this the second element you are talking about in the question, or you mean second `Cell` or second `Data` element?!!

Comment: One `Row` contains two elements of `Cell`. Seems like `getTextContent()` returns only text of it's cells and spaces.

Comment: @gooamoko It looks like in td I get all the excel table row data ( all the columns on a specific row, in this case is row with id `1`)

Comment: @KAD In `td` now I have the text from all the `<Data>`'s what I want is just the value from the second `<Cell>` ( the text from the `<Data>` of the second `<Cell>`

Comment: @John Doe So, if you need only one `Cell` in second `Row` - you need to make one step more to process XML structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shall update your code as below, in order to fetch the children of the second row, to get the second `Cell` and then get the text node of that cell:

```
File fXmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Worksheet"); // getting the tags "Worksheet"
Node nNode = nList.item(0); // getting the first "worksheet" tag
Element eElement = (Element) nNode; //getting the content of the worksheet tag


Element secondRow = (Element)  eElement.getElementsByTagName("Row").item(1);
Element secondCell = (Element)   secondRow.getElementsByTagName("Cell").item(1);
String secondCellText = secondCell.getTextNode();
```

Comment: Now that you said it, seems pretty legit that this was the solution, thank you!